# Is django can modify variable value in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to write a template that renders something only one time.

My idea is to create a flag variable to check it is the first time.

My code

```
{% with "true" as data %}
    {% if data == "true" %}
        //do something
        ** set data to "false" **
    {% else %}
        //do something
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

I don't know **How to change a variable in django template.** Is it possible? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to do this from a for loop ([`forloop.first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for))? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sayse thank you this solution can solve my problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done with a Django custom filter

[django custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/)

```
def update_variable(value):
    data = value
    return data

register.filter('update_variable', update_variable)

{% with "true" as data %}
    {% if data == "true" %}
        //do somethings
        {{update_variable|value_that_you_want}}
    {% else %}
        //do somethings
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Thank you,But Is it have another way for change variable value by don't using custom tag or custom filter ?

Comment: template should contain only rendering logic do all these computation in django view.

Comment: A with statement would be better. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324839/update-value-of-a-variable-inside-a-template-django

Comment: What if I don't want to print  that variable?

Comment: Return nothing `return ""`

Answer (score 8):

NIKHIL RANE's answer doesn't work for me. Custom [simple_tag()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#django.template.Library.simple_tag) can be used to do the job:

```
@register.simple_tag
def update_variable(value):
    """Allows to update existing variable in template"""
    return value
```

and then use it like this:

```
{% with True as flag %}
    {% if flag %}
        //do somethings
        {% update_variable False as flag %}
    {% else %}
        //do somethings
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```