# Django template loop where last item value is not Null

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, loops, jinja2

DB data:

```
pk,text
2|null
3|foo
4|null
5|bar
6|null
```

I intend to loop the given data, but I only want to iterate over items where `text`  column value is `NOT null`. Also, I need to know which is the *last*  value where `text` column is `NOT null`.

This is my intended view once the template has rendered:

```
3 foo
5 bar *last*
```

In python, such is achieved by an if condition in list comprehension, such as:

```
[x for x in my_loop if x != None]
```

Rendering this in the *views.py* is massively inconvenient due to how this data is also used in the rest of the template, and this would also gobble up too much unnecessary memory.

However, is this possible to do when rendering in django template?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can iterate reverse and the first item having a `text` value `NOT NULL` access its _index_ or whatever you want to with that object. Hope it answers your question :)

Comment: Possible, however...
That would require a variable to flag that a `text` value was present...

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item.text %}
     <span>{{ item.text }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I currently do. However, how do I catch the last item in that loop where _text_ is NOT null?

Comment: Look at the section in this link under the "for" section. Specifically `forloop.last`. You can add that ti your `{% if %}` statement with an `and` clause. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: That way _pk:6_ will print out. I need _pk:5_ to be flagged up as the last item, and not _pk:6_. Any more ideas?

Comment: Use the `forloop.counter` to check if the length of the list is equal to the counter. `{% if items|length == forloop.counter %}`

Comment: Oh, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood what you were asking. This definitely sounds like something that should be done in the view logic, though. Otherwise you could create a custom template tag to change template variables and update the variable as you loop through.

Comment: Here's another SO post that will get you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916408/is-django-can-modify-variable-value-in-template