# Conditional Counter in Django template for loops

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop, django-templates

I want my for loop to end after the if-condition is satisfied thrice while rendering my "products" details in my eCommerce website.

## category.html

```
    {% for item in subcategory %}
    {% with counter="0" %}
    <div>
        <h5 class="my-0" style="font-weight: 700;">{{ item.title }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        {% for i in products %}
        {% if i.category.id == item.id %}
        {{ counter|add:"1" }}
        {% if counter == "3" %}
            {{ break}}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="col-3 p-0 px-1 my-3">
            <a href="{% url 'product_detail' i.id i.slug %}">
                <img class="w-100" id="catbox" src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="">
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="col-3 p-0 my-3   text-center"
            style="border-radius: 10px;background: url({% static 'images/temp.jpeg' %}); background-size: cover;">
            <div class="h-100 w-100 m-0 p-0" style="background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.61);border-radius: 10px;">
                <div style="position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);">
                    <a href="{% url 'category_product' item.id item.slug %}" class="text-white " href="#"><strong>SEE
                            ALL</strong></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
```

I want the second for loop, i.e., `{% for i in products %}` to break once the if condition, i.e., `{% if i.category.id == item.id %}` inside it is satisfied **thrice**. But the counter I set to 0 is incremented to 1 repeatedly instead of being incremented recurrently with the for loop. Since there is an if condition inside it I can not use forloop.counter too.
I want this process to repeat for each iteration of the first for loop, i.e., `{% for item in subcategory %}`

Answer (score 1):

No template tag exists for breaking(or continue like in python) purposes. It's often a bad practice to send your data unprocessed and working in the template. I think at first you need to make a list based on your conditions in views then pass that to the template to work with them.
However, you can do one thing(very inefficient according to me),

```
{% if counter <= 3 %}
   do the job which you meant to do before breaking
{% endif %}
```

or you can try to create your own template tags/filters. But I will suggest you keep it simple in the template and mess up with it in the view. [view docs for template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: also how to declare and increment the counter?

Comment: {{ counter|add:"1"}} adds 1 to the counter and makes it value from 0 to 1 repeatedly instead of incrementing the value of counter recurrently with the iteration of the for loop.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about that, 
Normally, you can't do that. To do that you have to declare a custom template tag which is pretty easy. 
Here you will get an example: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31916408/is-django-can-modify-variable-value-in-template)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define counter by yourself and with the 'with' tag. you can use django built-in counter for the loops. You can access the counter in a for-loop like this: `{{ forloop.counter }}` starting with 1 and the `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` starting from 0. and also you can access the counter of an outer for-loop counter like this: `forloop.parentloop.counter/counter0` check [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/)

Comment: yeah, I know about this one. But I have many 'products' and out of them, I wanna show only 3 products that satisfy the mentioned if condition. If I use forloop.counter it will simply count the number of 'products' and not the number 'products' that satisfies the if condition.
Adding to it, how can I break from the for loop in Django templates?